# npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Getting the following error when running npm install on react project.

```
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/ramin/dev/frontend-v2/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/ramin/dev/frontend-v2/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ramin/dev/frontend-v2/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

I am relatively new to node and googling the error I couldn't find much. Any thoughts on what is causing this error?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @ParagPawar I think we ended up using yarn install instead and didn't get that issue. But it was a while ago so hopefully my memory is not tricking me. Also did you try dvera's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Deleting package-lock.json and then rerunning 'npm install' worked for me.